# In Java how fast is accessing a value of an Array of Integers vs accessing a single Integer variable?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a parent class which has an array of `ints`, but 1/3 of the child classes need only need one integer.

I'm wondering here if it is just as fast to just use the `intAry[0]` for those classes or not.

Comment: Premature optimization is evil

Comment: @VinceEmigh If the two versions of the code are equivalent in terms of complexity and readability, there is no harm in choosing the faster one. Although in this specific case I doubt there is a significant difference.

Comment: @assylias "*Although in this specific case I doubt there is a significant difference*" That's why it's evil, and the harm comes in the form of wasted time and effort. Optimizing things before you even know they need to be optimized could be a huge time waster, resulting in a developer spending an hour on the subject just to realize he only saved a few nanoseconds. This is a perfect example of that.

Comment: @VinceEmigh What I meant is that the quote needs to be qualified. It does not mean: writing sloppy code is ok until you have discovered a bottleneck. It means don't spend time on optimising something that does not matter. So it does apply in this case but is being abused in cases where ti does not apply. You get the drift...

Comment: @assylias Yes, I understand, but how do you check whether something matters or not if you do not have the skill to make accurate assumpsions? You'd have to profile it to see what matters. It's not a "write sloppy code til something breaks, then fix everything" rather than "there could be more severe problems in your code for all you know."

Comment: @VinceEmigh Well I did already finish the code. This is part of an input-polling system for raw input from gamepads/joysticks, keyboard, mouse, and tablet including macros and multi-binds and it's finished and working. Since it is a polling system, it will be called very often and I wanted to optimize wherever possible that seems like it might matter.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing an array, there is a bounds check involved, which does not happen when accessing a single variable. However taking into account `JIT` processor cache effects and other such things, it becomes more complicated and you can't easily draw reliable conclusions.

You'd be wise to concentrate on actual hotspots.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an array index in java is conceptually always slower than accessing a normal field. This is because the field is directly contained in the objects memory, while in case of the array index it requires first reading the field, and then an additional read for the index. It can also incur an additional penalty for checking if the index is in bounds, which the JIT may not be able to optimize away (basically this means *another* read of the array length plus compare and a hopefully correctly predicted branch).

On the other hand, *if* your class happend to be monomorphic before, introducing a subclass may add an additional cost for actually invoking the methods.

While the difference *can* be significant in *tight loops*, its not notable in more complex designs where a significant part of the total execution time is spent elsewhere.

As many comments already pointed out, attempting to optimize this before you even have written the code and without any hints where most of the time is spent, is premature optimization and most likely wasted time and effort.

Comment: I actually did finish the code. It is part of an organized input polling system and I'm just optimizing everything since it is called very often.

Comment: @Meesch Optimizing "everything", while maybe tempting is not economic. In any typical program, as a rule of thumb, 10% of the code eats 90% of the execution time. Optimizing anything other that these 10% is uneconomical, because if you optimized *all* the code, you'll invest either 10x the time, *or to put it worse*, 9/10ths of your precious time were *wasted* to optimize the 90% that did only contribute 10% to the performance. Thats why you first profile to find out *what* to optimize, then pick out those 10% and concentrate 100% of your effort *there*.